# How to pass client side javascript return value to ASP classic server side

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

## javascript

```
       function test(abc) {
         var ddlArray = new Array();
            var ddl = document.getElementById('AdjusterList');
          for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
            ddlArray[i] = ddl.options[i].value;
          }
  var indexsel = ddl.selectedIndex;
      return indexsel ;            
     }
```

---

## ASP

```
                 strArrayCRN = osRecordSet.RecordCount
                 strArrayCRN2 = osRecordSet2.RecordCount
                 dim StrCount 
                 StrCount =strArrayCRN+strArrayCRN2
```

---

## HTML +ASP

```
<select name="AdjusterList" id="AdjusterList" onchange='test("<%=StrCount%>")'><%
%>
   <option value="0">Please choose an option from the list.</option>
  <% Do While (osRecordSet.EOF = False)
       %><option value="<%=osRecordSet.RowPosition%>">
          <%=osRecordSet.Fields("NAME")%></option>
      <%
     osRecordSet.MoveNext
      Loop        %><%
    Do While (osRecordSet2.EOF = False)
            %><option value="<%=osRecordSet2.RowPosition%>">
           <%=osRecordSet2.Fields("NAME")%></option>
       <%   osRecordSet2.MoveNext    Loop        %>
```

Here i want to pass the return value of  function test() i.e value of the selected index to asp server side

Comment: put the value you want to send in a hidden field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to send it to server during normal html page submit, put the return value in hidden field.

If you want to send the value before the form submit, use AJAX.

**Hidden Field method**

JavaScript

```
function test(abc) {
         var ddlArray = new Array();
            var ddl = document.getElementById('AdjusterList');
          for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
            ddlArray[i] = ddl.options[i].value;
          }
  var indexsel = ddl.selectedIndex;
      document.getElementById("returnValueField").value = indexsel;
      return indexsel ;            
     }
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="returnValueField" name="returnValueField" />
```

In ASP access this hidden field like an other form field.

For AJAX use some library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to make things [easier](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

**Using AJAX with jQuery**

First you need to [include](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Setup) the jQuery library in your page.

Then modify your function like this

```
function test(abc) {
             var ddlArray = new Array();
                var ddl = document.getElementById('AdjusterList');
              for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
                ddlArray[i] = ddl.options[i].value;
              }
      var indexsel = ddl.selectedIndex;
          // Ajax call starts
          $.ajax({
                 url: "your_asp_page_to_handle_request.asp",
                 data: {"selected_index": indexsel },
                 success: function() { 
                    alert("I am back after sending data sucessfully to server.");}
                 });
          // Ajax call ends  

          return indexsel ;            
         }
```

Your ASP code in **your_asp_page_to_handle_request.asp** will be something like this

```
<%

dim selectedIndex
selectedIndex = Request.QueryString("selected_index")

%>
```

Please note that you can also use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of the Ajax function we used above.

Comment: Are you ok with using jQuery?